# I want to swap html pages without having the user click an html<a> reference

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a program swap to a different page after finishing a `for(){}` loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: What language did you use for the `for()` loop? PHP? It would be good to add some code showing what you have done.

Comment: window.location.href = 'http://www.google.ca';

Comment: the for loop was done in javascript. I deleted it because it didn't work. Basically I was creating a game to run ten times then swap to another page to show the results. I will try to rebuild it and add to the post.

Comment: questions is lacking enough information to make any education assumptions

Comment: for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    makeBox();// creates a box randomly on the screen
    document.getElementById("myBox").onclick=function(){
         this.style.display="none";
         clickedTime = Date.now();
         reactionTime = (clickedTime - createdTime) / 1000;
         document.getElementById("time").innerHTML="Reaction time is "+reactionTime+" seconds";
      makeBox();
    }
    // this is where I want to change to another html page to show 
    // the times of reaction
  }

Comment: can I use "<a href>" without having to click on the reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "swap to a different page"? Are you trying to do a redirect? And if so, server side or client side?

Comment: trying to load up a second html page. i guess thats a redirect

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

You can use window.location.replace or window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

```
for(loop) {
    //stuff happens here;
}
window.location = "newPage.html";
```

in javascript `window.location` is the property that can change the url.
so if we were to do:

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
```

then we would be redirected to GOOGLE.